# How split alpinejs Main file in several small files?

Tags: alpine.js

Working with Bootstrap 4.5/jquery 3.3 / alpinejs 2.2 I wonder if there is a way make
1 Main file and several small files, like components?
It is possible to share data in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alpine.js components don't have a built-in way to communicate between them.

However they can use the `$dispatch` magic property to trigger custom events and use `x-on:custom-event-name.window` or `.document` to register listeners for window/document custom events.

Using that you can write multiple separate components and share information using custom events (you can find more patterns at https://codewithhugo.com/alpinejs-component-communication-event-bus/).

As to splitting into different files, there's no concept in Alpine.js of files/templates, if you're using a static site generator or a server-side templating engine, you can create partials and inject the markup in that fashion. Alpine.js is also fine evaluating new components injected into the HTML (using `element.innerHTML` or the Alpine.js `x-html` directive).

To share the Alpine.js "function components" you can put them into a `.js` file, and load them with a regular `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>`, as long as the function is defined on the global scope, Alpine.js will have no problems running it.